# Keyword search of Airbnb experiences?

Tags: airbnb

Is there a way to search Airbnb experiences by keyword (e.g. "tech", or "surf", or "coffee"). There are a few predefined options (e.g. time of day, language, and very broad category), but there doesn't appear to be a way of searching for a specific keyword?

#### Example

We can see all the results for [experiences in San Francisco](https://www.airbnb.com/s/San-Francisco--CA--United-States-/experiences?refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fexperiences&search_type=search_query&screen_size=large) - how can we return only the subset that contains a specific search term, e.g "coffee"?

Comment: I typed "coffee experiences in San Francisco, CA" and it took me to https://www.airbnb.com/s/Coffee-experiences-in-San-Francisco--CA/experiences happily.

Comment: @ceejayoz interesting. I think 'coffee' must be a label that is placed on listings (technically I don't think it's as versatile as a keyword, which could be absolutely anything). For a random example, 'Live Jazz and Chocolate-Making' doesn't show up when searching `chocolate experiences in San Francisco, CA`, but it *does* show up when searching `baking experiences in San Francisco, CA`. I guess 'baking' is another predefined label, but 'chocolate' isn't